# SwipeRefreshLayout error

Tags: android-activity, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to implement swiperefreshlayout and I am getting error at "this"

```
public class viewBets_activity extends ActionBarActivity {
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewbets);

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

    }


    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);

    }
}
```

I am getting error at `swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);`   screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: @AlexK sorry, added the error with screenshot.

Comment: I'm going to answer your question then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, now that you added the screenshot, the error is clear.

You're passing the wrong argument into `setOnRefreshListener()`! And of course, this makes sense, if you think about it. Your class is a `ActionBarActivity`. You're trying to set the `OnRefreshListener` as an `ActionBarActivity`...doesn't make any sense! You need to change your code to this:

```
swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh()
      {
      // what you want to happen onRefresh goes here
      }
  });
```

Here, you're creating a new OnRefreshListener object which you're adding as the listener.

For the future, in general, any time you have a `setOn______Listener()` method, the argument you'll be passing will be a `On_____Listener` object that you've customized. You can either created separately, or create it right in the set method the way I did in my answer.

Comment: roger that, I was just following this tut here..
http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

Comment: Gotcha. The way that that tutorial set things up is a bit different - it probably extended `OnRefreshListener`. I personally prefer the way I showed you!

Answer (score 0):

Your class is missing

```
implement SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener
```

This allows the listener to refer to the overridden method `onRefresh` when passing through `this` as the argument for `setOnRefreshListener`